# Python parser xPath

Tags: python, парсер, xpath

```
import requests
from lxml import html


response = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=gorrilaz&sp=CAE%253D')
parser_tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
content = parser_tree.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "yt-lockup-thumbnail")]/a[@href]')

print(content)
print(type(content[0]))
```

Пытаюсь получить все ссылки на странице.
Почему в ответ приходит

> "Element a at 0x7ff2295f80e8">

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В переменной `content` у вас находятся объекты класса `lxml.html.HtmlElement` для того, чтобы вытащить ссылки, можем вызвать метод `get('href')` у каждого такого элемента:

```
In [5]: type(content[0])
Out[5]: lxml.html.HtmlElement

In [6]: links = [el.get('href') for el in content]

In [7]: links
Out[7]: 
['/watch?v=CJV08IuDtG8',
 '/watch?v=gMAGskTN9SM',
 '/watch?v=_pr0kBvbuNc',
 '/watch?v=7tsPhlmnsuQ',
 '/watch?v=pM7_UnguPp0',
 '/watch?v=nP6qhrdfTjs',
 '/watch?v=DH6EYKihEd4',
 '/watch?v=JChkWu6XLjI',
 '/watch?v=qolRTEITF6s',
 '/watch?v=qH7y8yQ48dg',
 '/watch?v=8VYLHwxd-e0',
 '/watch?v=5LrAW-roUWk',
 '/watch?v=D4vEtnOIqNs',
 '/watch?v=3Scp7rlqQ2Y',
 '/watch?v=ZAFJSbduMqg',
 '/watch?v=FolC7vZl4G4',
 '/watch?v=JF4Cujp52Qc',
 '/watch?v=iUHVHILLTyo',
 '/watch?v=83FdYHkPNC0',
 '/watch?v=c72k6n0q13o']
```